# Building the keras tuner best model with Sequential does not give the same results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, sequential, keras-tuner

For my regression , these are the results of the best model that I obtained using `keras-tuner`.

```
best_model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              64512     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                32800     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 97,345
Trainable params: 97,345
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I am tuning for three hyperparameters: neurons in 1st layer, neurons in 2nd layer and learning rate. I repeated this a few times and observed the number of neurons mostly remain the same. Following this, I decided to avoid tuning to save time, and instead manually define the model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))

## Compiling the model

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.001),
metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

filepath = "./dump/vol.weights.best.hdf" + str(i)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                                 monitor='val_root_mean_squared_error',
                                 verbose=1,
                                 save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                 mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=50,
                    batch_size=1,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    verbose=0)

model.load_weights(filepath)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

I have 30 splits of my dataset and I apply the model 30 times and save the weights in separate files in each iteration. The number of epochs is low now as I am just testing.

My results are very low compared to the results obtained when I apply the 'best' model obtained with `keras-tuner`. In fact, I don't even reload the libraries. The data splits are exactly the same. Everything is exactly the same! There is absolutely no difference except that I manually define the model but with the same parameters as returned by the tuner. Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Hope the question is clear. I can clear any doubts if needed.